# If $I$ and $J$ are distinct ideals in ring $R$ and $f:R \to R'$ is a homomorphism then is $f(I) = f(J)$?

Tags: ring-theory

The text book I am reading says that if $I$ is a subset of $J$ and $J$ is a subset of $I + \ker (f)$ then $f(I) = f(J)$. The argument goes: $f(I)$ is a subset of $f(J)$ is a subset of $f(I + \ker (f)) = f(I) + f(\ker (f)) = f(I)$ so the inclusions are all equalities.  I see that $f(\ker (f)) = 0$. What is disconcerting is $f(I + \ker (f)) = f(I) + f(\ker (f))$. I assume this is because $f$ is a homomorphism, but I am not used to seeing this property applied to a sum of sets! What might help me the most is an example.

Comment: I'm confused. Does the book claim $f(I) = f(J)$ or $f(I) \neq f(J)$?

Comment: Are you trying to disprove the claim in the title, or prove the claim in the body of the question that the books states?

Comment: The text book states that f(I) is not necesarily equal to f(J).

Comment: Yes. If $I\subset J$ then this is not true in general. But if $I\subset J \subset I+\ker f$ then it is true. Try writing the elements of the last set and then apply the homomorphism properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is coming from the following (side note - my $\subset$ includes equality):

If $I,J$ are distinct ideals in a ring $R$, then it is true that in general $f(I)\neq f(J)$. Why should the equality hold if $I\neq J$? (Of course, there are times when $f(I)=f(J)$, as an example this is true for every ideal in the $0$ morphism $f:R\rightarrow \{0\}$).

Now, let's assume $I\subset J$. Then it is still not true in general that $f(I)=f(J)$. This can be seen in the homomorphisms of say $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ under the ideals $(2)\supset (4)$. Here $(4)$ maps to $0$ but $(2)$ maps to $\{0,2\}$.

So when would it be true? Well, it is true if $I\subset J\subset I+\ker(f)$. This is because $f(I)\subset f(J)\subset f(I+\ker(f))=f(I)+f(\ker(f))=f(I)$.

Now, the last claim is true when we write down the elements of these sets. All elements of $I+\ker(f)$ are of the form $a+b$ where $a\in I$ and $b\in \ker(f)$. So the homomorphism properties apply and $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)=f(a)\in f(I)$. This is simply subset inclusion on the elements but written more simply to the entire sets.

An example of when this happens is in $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ and the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ being $(20)\subset (10)\subset (20)+(5)=(5)$. In this case all of these map to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f : \Bbb{Z}\to \Bbb{Z_2}$ such that $n \to n\ \text{mod}\ 2$.

Then $f(\Bbb{4Z})= f(2\Bbb{Z})$

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer In that case, see edit

Answer (score 1):

To address your concern in the body, in general, if $A,B\subseteq R$, then $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$ if $f$ is a homomorphism.

On the level of elements, let $a+b\in A+B$ be an arbitrary element of $A+B$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then 
$$
f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)\in f(A)+f(B)
$$
where the equality is by the homomorphism property. So $f(A+B)\subset f(A)+f(B)$.

Conversely, if $f(a)+f(b)\in f(A)+f(B)$ is arbitrary, again for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $f(a)+f(b)=f(a+b)\in f(A+B)$, where we've used the homomorphism property. So $f(A)+f(B)\subset f(A+B)$ and thus $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to note here is that, for any ideal $I$, you have
$$
f(I)=f(I+\ker f)
$$

Since it's obvious that $f(X)\subseteq f(Y)$ whenever $X\subseteq Y$, we just have to prove the converse inclusion.

Let $y\in f(I+\ker f)$; then, by definition, $y=f(x+z)$, where $x\in I$ and $z\in\ker f$. But then
$$
y=f(x+z)=f(x)+f(z)=f(x)+0=f(x)
$$
so we get that $y\in f(I)$.

Now you put this together with the standard inclusion and, from $I\subseteq J\subseteq I+\ker f$ you get
$$
f(I)\subseteq f(J)\subseteq f(I+\ker f)=f(I)
$$
which means $f(J)=f(I)$.

You can try your hand to another similar problem:

> for ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$, we have $f(I)=f(J)$ if and only if $I+\ker f=J+\ker f$.